# Using CheckboxSelectMultiple inside a form that uses input from DB related to User using ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called `Level1` which is related to `User` model using `ForeignKey`

```
class Level1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

IT takes input from user and saves it in DB. I can get all the inputs that are given by the specific user by using

```
user=request.user
level1_answers=user.level1_set.all()
```

(**IF there is another method, please do share**)

Now what I want to do is to use these answers from level1 (`level1_answers`) and use them as an input for the Level2.

Where Level 2 is a model same as Level1 with `ForeignKey` as  User and `ans` except the fact that **Instead of taking new answers as input, It uses the answers from level1 and presents the user with Checkboxes from those.**

```
class Level2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    #I want ans to  be presented as CheckboxSelectMultiple using Level1 answers.
```

If user has answered `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` for `Level1`, I want to show Checkboxes to select from these and save this in DB in table `Level2`.

Comment: It's not clear how Level1 and Level2 relate to each other and what exactly is the result - creating a CheckboxSelectMultiple from a mere CharField sounds like magic. Also, this is very vague for an SO question. This site is not for requesting a complete solution from scratch but for getting help with concrete implementation details.

Comment: ```Level1``` get some data say  ```Data1``` and ```Level2``` uses that ```Data1``` to create checkboxes.and save the results in ```Data2```.

Comment: @Risadinha maybe it can help you to understand in a different way. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)